# Face recognition with "Beyond Reality Face JS"

Tags: javascript, node.js, face-recognition

I want make app in node.js with face recognition using Beyond Reality Face. I decided to compare distance between eyes, length of the nose, et cetera ... So i need coordinates(x,y) of face shape points. Does anyone know how to simply get coordinates of selected point in this library ?

Comment: did you read the library documentation? what did it say?

Comment: I couldn't find anything

Comment: did you ask them to point you to usable documentation on http://www.tastenkunst.com/#/contact ?